# child process is not working in electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I'm creating a child process using "fork" in the "electron" app.
I'm creating child process as below:

```
   const child_process_file = path.join(__dirname, 'getSubFolders.js')
   const sub = fork(child_process_file, [JSON.stringify(subFolderObj), JSON.stringify(arg)])
```

when I run this program in debug mode, the child process is working fine, but when I generate an exe file and run the exe file, child process is not working as it should be.
It is targetting main.ts(main file) instead of a file('getSubFolders.js' here) passed in params while creating child process.

path generated for child_process_file is =>  C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Programs\INSTALLED_EXE_PATH\resources\app.asar\two-way-sync\getSubFolders.js

can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: __dirname is not defined? Can u console log the full path child_process_file in both debug as well as release mode.

Comment: @Shirshak55 __dirname gives us current working directory debug "child_process_file" path => D:\CODE_PATH\two-way-sync\getSubFolders.js exe "child_process_file" path => C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Programs\INSTALLED_EXE_PATH\resources\app.asar\two-way-sync\getSubFolders.js

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution and it is working for me.

```
const env = { ...process.env, PATH: `${process.env.PATH}:/usr/local/bin` };
const child_process_file = path.join(__dirname, 'getSubFolders.js')
const sub = fork(child_process_file, [JSON.stringify(subFolderObj), JSON.stringify(arg)], {
                  env,
                  stdio: ['ipc', out, err]
})
```

Make sure that you are not using any electron functionality in child process